# drawing the graph and finding intercepts from equation not in y=mx+c form

Tags: functions

I have the equation: $x+4y = 0$.

Its not in the form of $y=mx+c$ so I am unsure of how to find the intercepts and draw the graph. I know that generally when $x+4y=12$ then you just make one variable $= 0$ and find the other variable but since the constant is $0$ I am unsure how to find these variables. So how would I find the points/intercepts of this equation and what would it look like on a graph?

Comment: $x+4y=0$, $y=-\frac14x$.

Comment: Use exactly the same method you used for $x+4y=12$.  Changing the $12$ to $0$ really makes no difference at all.

Comment: It makes a big difference, because the method of working out the two intercepts and connecting them only works if there are two intercepts.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in y-intercept form. which is $y=mx+b$. The graph would have a negative slope. I think you can go from there and figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x+4y = 0\implies $$\begin{align} 
y&=-\dfrac14 x+0\\  y&=\ \ \ \ mx+c\\ \end{align}$